# Regex capture number before specific word Google Script

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

I need to capture phone number before specific word "Congratulations"?

Here an example:

```
Billing address
Houston
77990
013XXXXXXX

Congratulations on your purchase.
```

Regex:

`013XXXXXXX`

Code:

`(\w+)(?=\s+Congratulations)`

`(.+)(?=\s+Congratulations)`

`(\d+)(?=\s+C)`

I use this three regular expression but google script does not return anything while in regex101.com its work just fine

Is it because lookahead cannot be used in google appscript?

Comment: Is the string always the same length?  Could it be an assumption that the string you're trying to match is always the same length or is always preceded by a certain number of digits?

Comment: No, only specific word (Congratulations) is the same and phone number is always before the word (Congratulations)

Comment: Is the phone number human entered or is it computer cleansed and in a particular format then?  It's a string of all numbers possibly with special characters?  Are you needing to account for international number formats?

Comment: Try `/^[\(\) 0-9-]{6,}$/`

Comment: Human entered and might need to account for international number formats. But if not possible, i only will considered phone number entered by human

Comment: Show your code. The regex isn't enough.

Comment: Not sure if it will work now, but if you use the value of the capturing group, you don't need the lookahead `(\w+)\s+Congratulations`

Answer (score 2):

```
var re=/^[\(\) 0-9-]{6,}$/m;
var matchA=s.match(re);
```

[string match method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Comment: This will find telephone numbers entered like this: 812-555-4875 or (812) 555-4875, but could miss some rare international formats or if the number is entered with a + sign at the front.  I might suggest ^[\/+\(\) 0-9-]{6,}$ instead.  Otherwise, Cooper's answer is good.  the `s` is a variable intending to represent the whole message that you are trying to match.  Negative lookaheads take a lot more time whereas this would be very quick.  Only other issue could be if there is a chance of other information that is enterd that has 6 or more number characters in it in the string.

Comment: I was thinking that you have to escape the parentheses. Adding the plus sign might be good.  I tested this in UltraEdit and seems to work. But it may not be the perfect expression for a telephone number. It wasn’t clear from the example how the number was going to be formatted.